# Clear Input onFocus with Google Custom Search

Tags: javascript, google-search

I'm moving a sites search over to google custom search.

The old input for text looks like this:

```
<input type="text" value="Search this website..." name="s" id="searchbox" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search this website...') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search this website...';}" />
```

Now I need to Have the attr 'name' as 'q', like so:

```
<input type="text" value="Search this website..." name="q" id="searchbox" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search this website...') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search this website...';}" />
```

The odd thing is that when I swap the name over to q, I'm unable to clear the search box on focus. Am I missing something super easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you also including the CSE JS?  Chances are it's overwriting your focus and blur handlers.  The [default implementation](http://www.google.com/cse/) (see top of page) adds a Google-branded watermark.

You can implement CSE without their JS, and in that case your code works fine:

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/cse" id="cse-search-box">
    <input name="cx" type="hidden" value="yoursearchid" />
    <input name="ie" type="hidden" value="UTF-8" />
    <input name="q" type="text" value="Search this website..." onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search this website...') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search this website...';}" />
    <input name="sa" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why that would happen, but I recommend you don't use JavaScript to do that and let HTML do it's job with the `placeholder` attribute:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search this website..." name="q" id="searchbox" />
```

Comment: Haha, I wish the whole world would :|

Comment: You'll need a HTML5 doctype too. See my post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984311/delete-default-value-of-an-input-text-on-click/2984373#2984373, that interestingly outranked the accepted answer by 3. After that, the answerer changed his answer to support mine - horrible for information preservation, but a nice gesture.