# Delete default value of an input text on click

Tags: javascript, html, input, default-value

I have an input text:

```
<input name="Email" type="text" id="Email" value="email@abc.example" />
```

I want to put a default value like "What's your programming question? be specific." in Stack Overflow, and when the user click on it the default value disapear.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

For future reference, I **have** to include the HTML5 way to do this.

```
<input name="Email" type="text" id="Email" value="email@abc.example" placeholder="What's your programming question ? be specific." />
```

If you have a HTML5 doctype and a HTML5-compliant browser, this will work. However, **many browsers do not currently support this**, so at least Internet Explorer users will not be able to see your placeholder. However, see [JQuery HTML5 placeholder fix « Kamikazemusic.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20100325081314/http://www.kamikazemusic.com/quick-tips/jquery-html5-placeholder-fix/) for a solution. Using that, you'll be very modern and standards-compliant, while also providing the functionality to most users.

Also, the provided link is a well-tested and well-developed solution, which should work out of the box.

Comment: Good answer, very relevant nowadays. Works good as `<textarea placeholder="Write something..."></textarea>` too.

Comment: value="" seems to overrides the placeholder and it doesn't work with both of them present.

Comment: @Brian: The link works for me, but I added a link to archive.org's version of the page from around the time I wrote this answer. Keep in mind that that was in 2010 - nowadays [all modern browsers support the placeholder attribute](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder), so you shouldn't need - and probably shouldn't use - a compatibility-enhancing script.

Answer (score 64):

Although, this solution works, I would recommend you try [MvanGeest's solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984311/delete-default-value-of-an-input-text-on-click/2984337#answer-2984373) which uses the `placeholder`-attribute and a JavaScript fallback for browsers which don't support it yet.

If you are looking for a Mootools equivalent to the jQuery fallback in MvanGeest's reply, [here is one](http://mootools.net/forge/p/mootools_placeholder).

--

You should probably use `onfocus` and `onblur` events in order to support keyboard users who tab through forms.

Here's an example:

```
<input type="text" value="email@abc.example" name="Email" id="Email"
 onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'email@abc.example';}"
 onfocus="if (this.value == 'email@abc.example') {this.value = '';}" />
```

Comment: Seconded. -1 for DOM pollution, there are more semantic solutions (not to mention cleaner, shorter etc.)

Comment: What do you mean with "polluting the DOM"? Do you mean using the event attributes? What's wrong with that?

Comment: @MvanGeest: Show us one :) I've done this a long time and while I'd make this unobtrusive script, I disagree with your shorter argument.  Can you show me *anything* shorter and works *now* in a cross-browser way, notice I said **now**, not 5 years from now.

Comment: @Nick: take a look at my answer. It now includes a JavaScript-only function for doing just this. In terms of characters, it's just about the same length as the DOM-pollution shown in this answer.

Comment: The shorter argument only applies when there's more than 1 of these inputs, which of course depends on the type of form (search/registration/...). Even then, I'd have to select the elements first... for which I would use jQuery... you're probably right :) And I've only got a few years of experience; I'm simply a purist.

Comment: @roosteronacid - Your method is a) longer, and b) doesn't do the same thing, as I mentioned in comments on your answer, you don't check for a valid **non-default** value when focusing.  I don't disagree it's the way to go, that's why my comment said "I'd make this unobtrusive script", but it's not shorter and is not any more "DOM" polluting...exactly how does it pollute the DOM?  It's a perfectly valid way of attaching an event handler, *preferred*? no, *valid*? absolutely.  What if the page was a post result, and the value wasn't `email@abc.com` initially? This works, your's doesn't.

Comment: I thought the asker just wanted a simple solution, so I just gave him the simplest without much second thought. But, I think the ideal solution (as you have pointed out) would be to use the `placeholder`-attribute with a Javascript fallback for browsers who don't support it yet.

Comment: @Nick: I think my code does exactly what AZIRAR wants. The code provided in this answer is the very definition of DOM pollution: cramming JavaScript (or in-line styles for that matter) into your HTML.

Comment: @mq.chen: This is fast and easy, sure. But I think you're being a bit too pragmatic :)

Comment: @roosteronacid - You're confusing **clean source** with a **clean DOM**, these are 2 *very* different concepts.  This is an *alternative way of attaching the handler*, the DOM will see very little difference between this an an unobtrusive method. The markup *is not the DOM*, it's the structure from which the DOM is initialized.

Comment: @Nick: you're right. Polluting the source is what I'm getting at.

Comment: IMHO there is nothing wrong with using the HTML attributes. Most importantly its not "polluting the DOM". It is the best and most reliable way to set event listeners that work immediately without having to wait for on-DOM-ready/onload. The only improvement that could be done would be to extract the inline code into functions.

Comment: As long as placeholder behavior will not erase the placeholder text on focus, placeholder will be unusable.

Comment: does anyone knows what I have to do if I want an empty field when press the submit button when value is value="email@abc.com" brgds!

Comment: @sebastian_h I recommend you use the `placeholder` attribute. It is made for these situations in mind, and there are several scripts that add compatability for old browsers. Check out @MvanGeest's answer below.

Comment: @mqchen thank you.. i read about and it seems that modernizer can help... i will try. brgds

Answer (score 26):

This is somewhat cleaner, i think. Note the usage of the "defaultValue" property of the input:

```
<script>
function onBlur(el) {
    if (el.value == '') {
        el.value = el.defaultValue;
    }
}
function onFocus(el) {
    if (el.value == el.defaultValue) {
        el.value = '';
    }
}
</script>
<form>
<input type="text" value="[some default value]" onblur="onBlur(this)" onfocus="onFocus(this)" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 7):

Using jQuery, you can do:

```
$("input:text").each(function ()
{
    // store default value
    var v = this.value;

    $(this).blur(function ()
    {
        // if input is empty, reset value to default 
        if (this.value.length == 0) this.value = v;
    }).focus(function ()
    {
        // when input is focused, clear its contents
        this.value = "";
    }); 
});
```

And you could stuff all this into a custom plug-in, like so:

```
jQuery.fn.hideObtrusiveText = function ()
{
    return this.each(function ()
    {
        var v = this.value;

        $(this).blur(function ()
        {
            if (this.value.length == 0) this.value = v;
        }).focus(function ()
        {
            this.value = "";
        }); 
    });
};
```

Here's how you would use the plug-in:

```
$("input:text").hideObtrusiveText();
```

Advantages to using this code is:

- Its unobtrusive and doesn't pollute the DOM
- Code re-use: it works on multiple fields
- It figures out the default value of inputs by itself

Non-jQuery approach:

```
function hideObtrusiveText(id)
{
    var e = document.getElementById(id);

    var v = e.value;

    e.onfocus = function ()
    {
        e.value = "";
    };

    e.onblur = function ()
    {
        if (e.value.length == 0) e.value = v;
    };
}
```

Comment: 3 comments here: 1) `if (this.value == v) this.value = v;` should be `if (this.value === "") this.value = v;`, 2) You're clearing the value on focus, even if it's a valid, non-default value, and 3) Don't *assume* they're using jQuery.

Comment: Aye. I spotted the mistake and corrected it. Thanks thou Nick :)

Comment: Your solution still clears the element if I put any input and re-focus the element, this wouldn't be desirable behavior.

Comment: @NickCraver, do we really need to use `===` in this case?  I think we can always assume that a text input's value is a string and nothing but `""` would evaluate?

Answer (score 3):

Enter the following 
inside the  tag, just add onFocus="value=''" so that your final code looks like this:

```
<input type="email" id="Email" onFocus="value=''">
```

This makes use of the javascript onFocus() event holder.

Answer (score 2):

we can do it without using js in the following way using the "placeholder" attribute of HTML5
( the default text disappears when the user starts to type in, but not on just clicking )

`<input type="email" id="email" placeholder="xyz@abc.example">`

see this: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_placeholder

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `placeholder` tag in your input instead of `value`

Comment: I did not know that attribute existed and it works great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`<input name="Email" type="text" id="Email" placeholder="enter your question" />`

The placeholder attribute specifies a short hint that describes the expected value of an input field (e.g. a sample value or a short description of the expected format).

The short hint is displayed in the input field before the user enters a value.

Note: The placeholder attribute works with the following input types: text, search, url, tel, email, and password.

I think this will help.

Comment: You're showcasing the use of placeholder but a quick description on the topic would really help others.

Comment: I have edited my answer and i hope this much description about placeholder will help people.

Answer (score 0):

Here is very simple javascript. It works fine for me :

```
// JavaScript:

function sFocus (field) {
    if(field.value == 'Enter your search') {
        field.value = '';
    }
    field.className = "darkinput";
}

function sBlur (field) {
    if (field.value == '') {
        field.value = 'Enter your search';
        field.className = "lightinput";
    }
    else {
        field.className = "darkinput";
    }
}
// HTML
<form>
  <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    class="lightinput"
    onfocus="sFocus(this)" 
    onblur="sBlur(this)"
    value="Enter your search" name="s" id="s"
  />
</form>
```

Comment: You should show how to hook it up too.  The functions do nothing by themselves.

Comment: <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="" >
 <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for</label>
 <input type="text" class="lightinput" onfocus="sFocus(this)" onblur="sBlur(this)" value="Enter your search" name="s" id="s" />
 <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="" />
 </div>
</form>

Answer (score 0):

Why remove value? its useful, but why not try CSS

```
input[submit] {
   font-size: 0 !important;
}
```

Value is important to check & validate ur PHP

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery solution. I always let the default value reappear when a user clears the input field.

```
<input name="Email" value="What's your programming question ? be specific." type="text" id="Email" value="email@abc.com" />

<script>
$("#Email").blur(
    function (){
        if ($(this).val() == "")
            $(this).val($(this).prop("defaultValue"));
        }
).focus(
    function (){
        if ($(this).val() == $(this).prop("defaultValue"))
            $(this).val("");
    }
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any really simple answers like this one, so maybe it will help someone out.

```
var inputText = document.getElementById("inputText");
inputText.onfocus = function(){ if (inputText.value != ""){ inputText.value = "";}; }
inputText.onblur = function(){ if (inputText.value != "default value"){ inputText.value = "default value";}; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way.

`#animal` represents any buttons from the DOM.
`#animal-value` is the input id that being targeted.

```
$("#animal").on('click', function(){
    var userVal = $("#animal-value").val(); // storing that value
    console.log(userVal); // logging the stored value to the console
    $("#animal-value").val('') // reseting it to empty
});
```