# Good jQuery Plugin for a Form Field Initial or Default Value?

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, input, default-value

What is a good jQuery plugin for a showing default value in an input box that disappears when it gets focus or a user starts entering text?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete default value of an input text on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984311/delete-default-value-of-an-input-text-on-click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class/type of plugins you're looking for are called watermark plugins, there are quite a few out there, for example [check jquery-watermark out](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/).

It depends on how much you want from it, there are also very minimal versions, [like In-Field](http://fuelyourcoding.com/scripts/infield/).

Answer (score 0):

I used this one and it works pretty well. http://fuelyourcoding.com/scripts/infield/

It's a bit quirky but works once you understand it