# How to remove default value of input on focus

Tags: jquery, input, default, onfocus

I have an input box that has default value text assigned to it. How can I remove this text when the user focuses on the field::

CoDE

```
<input type="text" name="kp1_description" value="Enter Keypress Description">
```

Comment: this is not an answer but in the future it will be  http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-placeholder-attribute

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete default value of an input text on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984311/delete-default-value-of-an-input-text-on-click)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var Input = $('input[name=kp1_description]');
    var default_value = Input.val();

    Input.focus(function() {
        if(Input.val() == default_value) Input.val("");
    }).blur(function(){
        if(Input.val().length == 0) Input.val(default_value);
    });
})​
```

That should do it.

Updated, Forgot that focus does not have a 2nd parameter for the focus-out event because there is none, it has to be chained with blur:

http://jsfiddle.net/hDCsZ/

you should also think about creating your own function for this such as:

```
$.fn.ToggleInputValue = function(){
    return $(this).each(function(){
        var Input = $(this);
        var default_value = Input.val();

        Input.focus(function() {
           if(Input.val() == default_value) Input.val("");
        }).blur(function(){
            if(Input.val().length == 0) Input.val(default_value);
        });
    });
}
```

Then use like so

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').ToggleInputValue();
})​
```

Comment: Updated again, sorry im half asleep :)

Answer (score 8):

Don't do it this way.  Use a jQuery watermark script:
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/

`$("input[name='kp1_description']").watermark("Enter Keypress Description")`;

There are a lot of things you have to account for if you do it manually. For instance, what happens when the text box loses focus? If there's no value, you'd want to readd your helper text.  If there is, you'd want to honor those changes.

Just easier to let other people do the heavy lifting :)

Comment: but using a whole library for a simple task is not the best idea.

Comment: True, I'm just of the opinion that this wheel doesn't need to be reinvented. There are lots of scenarios you have to consider and using the library can simplify that a lot. He tagged his question with jQuery so using a jQuery plugin is probably the most pragmatic way to accomplish this task.

Comment: +1 for code reuse. Some problems are hard and should be solved by a library and not reimplemented badly by every code monkey on the planet. People are especially bad about this when it comes to javascript.

Comment: it's funny because it may seems trivial, but actually there are many things to consider...

Answer (score 6):

With HTML5 you could do it without Javascript: just use [`placeholder`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML5_form_additions#placeholder) instead of `value`.
I think it's a nice addition, but of course you need to check the browser compatibility first.

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type="text" id="anything" placeholder="enter keypress description">
```

i think this will help

Answer (score 3):

```
$('input, textarea').each(function () {
    var Input = $(this);
    var default_value = Input.val();

    Input.focus(function() {
        if(Input.val() == default_value) Input.val("");
    }).blur(function(){
        if(Input.val().length == 0) Input.val(default_value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`var defaultForInput = "abc";`

`<input id="myTextInput" type="text" placeholder=defaultForInput />`

---

When submitting your form, check if the input(id="myTextInput") value is the 'empty-string', if so substitute it with (defaultForInput).

Answer (score 1):

**The Super Duper Short Version**

```
$('#input_id').focus(function() {
    $(this).val("");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" id="customer" value="Username"/>      
  <input type="Submit" value="Login" class="rc" />
</form>
```

**Javascript code:**

```
<script>
$('#customer').on({
    focus:function(){                   
      if(this.value == 'Username') this.value = '';
    },
    blur:function(){
      if(this.value == '') this.value = 'Username';
    }
})
</script>
```

That's all, I hope it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Plain JavaScript:

```
(function () {
  let input = document.querySelector ("input[name='kp1_description']");
  input.onfocus = function () {
    this.placeholder = this.value;
    this.value = '';
  };
})();
```

This keeps the value in the placeholder instead of removing it completely. If you do not like this, remove the placeholder line.