# How to remove default values of multiple inputs on focus

Tags: jquery, input, focus, default

there's a nice function created in the answer to this question [How to remove default value of input on focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806227/how-to-remove-default-value-of-input-on-focus), but how can it be re-used and applied to multiple input fields?

something like this, but working http://jsfiddle.net/hDCsZ/177/

basic I'm sure. thanks in advance.

Comment: The watermark plugin referenced in the linked discussion in your question  covers reuseability pretty well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/mpH6U/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var input = $('input');

    input.each(function(){
       $(this).data('default', $(this).val());
    }).focus(function(){
        if($(this).val() == $(this).data('default')){
            $(this).val("");
        }            
    }).blur(function(){
        if(!$(this).val()){
            $(this).val($(this).data('default'));
        }
    });  
})​
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `defaultValue` property:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("input").focus(function() {
        if(this.value == this.defaultValue) {
             this.value = "";
        }
    }).blur(function(){
        if(this.value.length == 0) {
           this.value = this.defaultValue;
        }
    });
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KhDVT/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/zSCn3/

Basically rather than writing the function twice we can use `.each` and have it apply to all available inputs. By using `.each` jQuery loops through each input and apply the function individually, so `default_value = $(this).val()` will be the value of a specific input.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){    
            var default_value = $(this).val();        
            $(this).focus(function() {
                if($(this).val() == default_value)
                {
                     $(this).val("");
                }
            }).blur(function(){
                if($(this).val().length == 0) /*Small update*/
                {
                    $(this).val(default_value);
                }
            });
        });
    })​;​
```