# Twitter style login switch

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

If you go to the twitter login page, you'll see that in the password field, it says: `password`. Then, if you fill in your password, it changes to an `<input type="password">`

How do they do that? I guess it has something to do with `onkeyup`, but I'm not quite sure.

If you can pass me links to tutorials or stuff like that, you're welcome. I already did a search for "Twitter style login" / "Twitter Style Input Fields" etc, but all I get are the tutorials for the dropdown login, wich they don't use anymore on their homepage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery/javascript - Input fields (user,pass) just like twitter's login?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275497/jquery-javascript-input-fields-user-pass-just-like-twitters-login)

Comment: http://www.diveintohtml5.org/forms.html explains the new HTML 5 input keywords

Comment: They are using effects to linearly increase the font from 0 to about 12px or so.  + they are using opacity adjustments.  If you noticed...both of these effects occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using HTML5, you can do it without Javascript using

```
<input type="password" placeholder="password">
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZmwCR/1/) as an example.