# How to clear the username and password in login form when they are wrong

Tags: authentication, joomla, passwords

I have a question

When an user type a wrong username and/or password and joomla display a message about this error and I would like to clean both fields, how can I do that ?

thank you for you help

Comment: I´m using the Joomla 2.5 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your Joomla root folder, from there:

- go to: `/templates/[your template]/html/mod_login`
- Backup default.php: `cp default.php default.php.org`
- Edit default.php: `vi default.php`
- And here's the tricky part, the thing you have to changes is different for each template, for example, in `atomic` template you should look for the line:

So the `id` of this field in this case is: `"modlgn_username"`. Now you can use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.removeData/) / [Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984311/delete-default-value-of-an-input-text-on-click) and "clean" the value.