# Position label text inside the text area

Tags: css, position, label

I have been playing around CSS for few hours now and I can't seem to get the result I want. Basically I want my label text to be displayed inside the textbox, so when you start typing it just disappears. Something like this [input --- enter your name --- input]

Real example: http://www.apartmani-pesa-zaton.hr/rezervacija

My label form:

```
<form class="email" id="forma-kontakt" action="send_mail.php" method="post">
        <div id="grid_kontakt">
                    <div id="grid_kontakt_l">
                        <p>
                            <label for="name">Ime i prezime *</label>
                            <input type="text" id="name" class="required" name="name" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="email">E-mail *</label>
                            <input type="text" id="email" class="required email" name="email" />
                        </p>
                    </div><!-- Grid kontakt left -->
                    <div id="grid_kontakt_r">
                        <p>
                            <label for="country">Država</label>
                            <input type="text" id="country" class="required" name="country" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="phone">Telefon</label>
                            <input type="text" id="phone" class="required" name="phone" />
                        </p>
                    </div><!-- Grid kontakt right -->
                    <p class="text">
                        <label for="message">Poruka *</label>
                        <textarea name="message" class="required" id="message"></textarea>
                    </p>
                    <p class="ar">
                        <em>Sva polja su obavezna!</em>
                        <input type="submit" class="send" value="POŠALJI" />
                    </p>
                </div><!-- Grid kontakt -->
            </form>
```

Comment: This : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984311/delete-default-value-of-an-input-text-on-click/2984337 is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the placeholder attribute, it is now widely supported.

```
<input type="text" id="name" class="required" name="name" placeholder="Ime i prezime *" />
```

Comment: i have created a demo with a fade-out effect using only css http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/QLxqe/

Answer (score 0):

I added all of the relevant CSS from your example site to your form using Chrome devloper tools.

http://jsfiddle.net/76VRz/54/

```
.email input[type=text], .forma input[type=email] {
width: 283px;
height: 47px;
padding: 0 15px;
background-position: 0 0;
}

.email label {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 47px;
line-height: 47px;
color: #383838;
font-size: 14px;
text-indent: 15px;
cursor: text;
}
```

This does overlay the label inside the input box although there must be an event wired up to dim the color and then remove it once there is a key press of value in the field.