# OffClick TextBox Event in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I write an application in C# ASP.NET and I have some problems. I have a TextBox which contains a default value "Search...". I use OnClick event to clear their content. What I need is that after editing the TextBox contains "Search..." again.

Comment: You use the server side event OnClick for this??

Comment: use onblur event of javascript.

Comment: Maybe he means javascript "onclick" event... In which case, Piter, maybe take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984311/delete-default-value-of-an-input-text-on-click