# How can I apply box-shadow to <span><input> so it looks like one single element to user?

Tags: html, css, forms

I am making a payment form where I want the amount input to have a leading $ sign. I've accomplished this with this html:

```
<div class="prefix">
    <span id="dollar">$</span>
    <input id="amount" type="number" name="amount">
</div>
```

I've removed the appropriate right and left borders using css to make the elements appear to be one.

This all works great. I however, would like to apply

```
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px #ddd;
```

to the span and input elements to match the styling on the rest of the site. The box-shadow, however, ends up making a shadow where the two elements meet. Like this:

```css
span,
input {
  border: 1px solid #777777;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px #ddd;
  border-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.prefix {
    display: flex;
}

.prefix #dollar {
    border-right: 0;
    padding: 7px 5px 7px 9px;
}
```

```html
<div class="prefix">
  <span id="dollar">$</span>
  <input id="amount" type="number" name="amount">
</div>
```

[![Illustration of problem, showing the visible shadow][1]][1]

[image]

I would like this to appear to the user as a single box with the light box shadow but without this vertical shadow after the '$'. I want to achieve this goal using js, html, and css.

I've tried to play with the margins to hide the shadow without success. I can hide the side of one of the boxes under the other using margins and z-index, this leaves a lighter, but still visible, line. Is there a technique to apply the box-shadow to these elements and achieve my desired result or am I wasting time trying to make it work? I imagine there is probably some simple solution but I am a noob at this html css stuff.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand the question, but it sounds to me that you're trying to add box-shadow to text which is... wrong and would look bad even if possible. If you want to add box-shadow to an element in the input, from a visual point of view (think UI/UX) it'll look bad. My advice, use js to concatenate input value with a $ and add the box-shadow to the input box. If you could draw/find an example to display your desired outcome perhaps I could offer you a workaround to your conundrum.

Comment: It might bee confusing for user with that dollar sign, they click in the input box and there is still a dollar sign, witch they can not remove. 
What you can do is to instead use a dollar sign as the default value for the input  box, and when user click on it, it will be removed. See this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984311/delete-default-value-of-an-input-text-on-click

Comment: Please could you edit the snippet I've made from your posted code so that it reproduces your problem? Also, as an aside, I'd personally prefer to keep the border/shadow there to show that the `$` symbol isn't directly editable by the user.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Sorry my question was not clear, I've updated the snippet created by @DavidThomas to show the problem.

Comment: So you're trying to create a solid border around the `.prefix` element? And for some reason the `border` property on the `.prefix` element isn't working for you? The snippet you edited (thank you!) shows that you don't seem to want a left-border on either the `<span>` or `<input>` elements?

Comment: @DavidThomas .prefix is just a div am using to group #dollar and #amount together. #dollar and #amount have those borders removed so they combine like a single input text field that starts with the $ sign but the $ sign will not be a part of the submitted data since it is only part of the span. This is done because I want <input> to be of type number. It is subtle but, box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px #ddd; add in inset shadow that gives the field a little sense of depth. If you run the snippet without the box-shadow css it removes the vertical line caused by the shadow but also the desired inset.